# What should we call "search at Stack Overflow"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search

I mean, there are some idioms such as:

> Google it = search it
>   tweet it, facebook me

What should we call "search at Stack Overflow" — *stack it*?

Comment: don't you mean "ask at Stack Overflow" instead of "search at Stack Overflow"? Searching in the content of Stack Overflow can done independently of the Stack Overflow site, using, for instance, Google.

Comment: @Peter I use this term("stack it") only for searching code. That is why, I asked because stackoverflow is the largest coding (code search, question-answer) on web

Comment: I came searching for this exact question. I used "stacking" in this question and thought it was very appropriate :) [link](http://superuser.com/questions/309665/automatically-clear-cache-of-all-major-browsers-installed)

Answer (score 11):

I don't think searching on Stack Overflow is going to develop its own verb, because searching is not the fundamental, central action on the site. "Googling" is the one thing you do on Google; "Tweeting" is the one thing you do on Twitter. "Facebooking" - connecting to other people - while by far not the *only* action, is arguably the central thing you do on that site.

The central action on Stack Overflow is asking and answering questions. Maybe that is too complex to create its own verb. That said, I don't think it needs one!

Comment: I propose all references to the word *question* be replaced with *Stack™*, all references to the word *answer* be replaced with *Pop™*, and all references to the word *ask* be replaced with *Overflow™*. So it's not "asking and answering questions", it's "Overflow™ing and Pop™ing Stack™s (patent pending)".

Comment: @Mark: *poping* should be *popping*, how do we handle that? Pop™ping? Popp™ing? Pop™p™ing?

Comment: A duplicate? [Blame It on the Pop™](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNzrwh2Z2hQ).

Answer (score 0):

Should we *SOS* something? Stack Overflow Search...

Answer (score -1):

I like **Stacko**, as in: "I don't know, just [Stacko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it."